# Formatting space between text and columns

Tags: formatting

I'm have some text and beneath that two align blocks in two columns. But the space between the equations and the text is way to large and i wan't to have that minimized somehow.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % tom header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Fjerner horizontale bar i toppen af dokumentet
\rfoot{Side \thepage \hspace{1pt} af \pageref{LastPage}} % Viser x ud af x sider, højre centreret
\usepackage[margin=1in,headheight=13.6pt]{geometry}
```

Tex code snippet:

```
For at kunne finde frem til en ligning eller rettere sagt en løsningsformel for den såkaldte kubisk ligning bliver vi nød til at lave en "depressed equation" $x^3+px*q$ hvor:
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{align*}
    p&=\frac{3ac-b^2}{3ac^2}
  \end{align*}\break
  \begin{align*}
    q&=\frac{2b^3-9abc+27da^3}{27a}
  \end{align*}
\end{multicols}
```

The compiled code looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please add a full MWE including your configuration of line-spacing and parksip.

Comment: Why do you go through the hassle with `multicols`?  Does something like this does want you want? `\begin{align*}
  p &=\frac{3ac-b^2}{3ac^2} & 
    q & =\frac{2b^3-9abc+27da^3}{27a}
\end{align*}`

Comment: It should be `$x^3+px+q$`, not `$x^3+px*q$`

Comment: No `$x^3+px+q$` is the right anwser here ;) it was my original code there was faulty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `align*` to achieve what you want; simply add a `&` between the parts of your equations:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

For at kunne finde frem til en ligning eller rettere sagt en
løsningsformel for den såkaldte kubisk ligning bliver vi nød til at
lave en ``depressed equation'' $x^3+px*q$ hvor:
\begin{align*}
  p &=\frac{3ac-b^2}{3ac^2} & 
    q &=\frac{2b^3-9abc+27da^3}{27a}
\end{align*}
formlen for en tredjedradsligning er som følge:

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Further, if you want double quotes, you should not use `"`; see code above.  Also, consider using `\times` instead of `*`: `$x^3+px\times q$` looks much better, IMHO.

Comment: It should be `+`, of course, not `*` or `\times`.